# How to indicate that another point is mentioned withou explicitly saying that?

Tags: punctuation, turning-point

In the email I'm writing there are three separate points. The last two ones are not so long so that each of them can fit in a single paragraph. However, the first one is needed to be split into two paragraphs. Because it's the most important point, I want to put it on top.

**Q:** How can I indicate that after finishing the first one, the second point is mentioned? Or, how to tell the reader that the third paragraph is not belonged to the first point?

I can explicitly say "as for point 2" at the beginning of the third paragraph, or simply divided the email into three sections with headings, but I want to find a subtler method to do that, for practicing writing skills purpose. I think the solution lies on the combination of white-space and punctuation.

Comment: Perhaps you should use page breaks

Comment: Use bullets at the beginning of each point (not each paragraph) and throw in some extra returns.

Comment: @DanielCann page break? There is no page in emails

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a signal at the start of each point.

For example, the first paragraph can begin, "First, I want to say blah blah blah..." and the second paragraph can continue your point. The third paragraph begins, "Secondly, there's this..." And the fourth paragraph signals itself as the last point with "Finally, this other point exists..."

Points two and three can be separated into short paragraphs or combined into one.

To make your structure even more clear, prelude the points with another signal, something like "Consider the following three points."

Comment: it seems that the only neat way to do is just explicitly say that.